# Watched tags slack notifications in stack overflow for teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, slack

Can you receive a slack notification for a question with a specific tag, if you use Stack Overflow for Teams?

[Documentation.](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/integrations/slack#)

Comment: Aren't you already notified in Slack when someone posts *any* question?

Comment: As per your own link *"Whenever someone asks a question, posts an answer, notifies you or adds a new comment, you’ll be notified on Slack within seconds."* So is your question how to **only** get notifications for specific tags?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! When setting up your Slack notifications you can specify a specific tag.